# Given $f$ is $o(1/x)$ as $x\to \infty$, is it true that $f$ is $o(1/x^{1+\epsilon})$ as well? (for some small enough $\epsilon>0$)

Tags: real-analysis

I'm basically trying to show that $f$ is summable $1$ to $\infty$ and that $f$ is integrable $1$ to $\infty$. Also, it necessary that $f$ be monotonic or continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Let $f(x)=\frac 1{x \log x}$.  This is $o(\frac 1x)$ but not $o(\frac 1{x^{1+\epsilon}})$

Answer (score -1):

No it's not.

Say $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^{1+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}$

Think about another approach to show that f is integrable

Comment: This is not a valid answer as you have to choose your function before $\epsilon $ is chosen.  We can take OP's $\epsilon$ to be $\frac 13$ of your $\epsilon$ and it is $o(\frac 1{x^{1+OP\epsilon}})$

Comment: It says "for some small $\epsilon$" so it's valid. If said "for any small $\epsilon$", you're right, your 1/xlogx example is better